# WPF Comparing two datatables to find matching values

Tags: sql, wpf, excel, oracle, datatables

enter code hereI have two data tables one of the data tables connects to sql server and the other connects to oracle.

I am running query statements on both and those work perfectly find.

Now I need to write something that will compare the "UNIT_NO" in oracle to the "VehicleName" in sql. yes they are the same number.

Right now the Oracle table bring in 6 columns and the SQL brings in 4 columns

an example would be:

VehicleName, VehicleGroupName, UserDefinedColumn2, UserDefinedColumn3

Unit_No, Unit_ID, Using_Dept, Status, Using_Dept_Desc,

I want my code to find the matching number from Unit_NO and VehicleName  and display all the above information all in one row. I was thinking linq but I cant get it to display correctly

```
This code combines the columns from both tables but pulls but does not add the any data in the rows any suggest or fixes 
private void GetSQLOraclelinqData()
        {

            var TstarData = GetTrackstarTruckData();
            var M5Data = GetM5Data();

            DataTable ComTable = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataColumn OraColumn in M5Data.Columns)
            {
                ComTable.Columns.Add(OraColumn.ColumnName, OraColumn.DataType); 

            }
            foreach (DataColumn SQLColumn in TstarData.Columns)
            {
                if (SQLColumn.ColumnName == "VehicleName")
                    ComTable.Columns.Add(SQLColumn.ColumnName + 2, SQLColumn.DataType);
                else
                    ComTable.Columns.Add(SQLColumn.ColumnName, SQLColumn.DataType);

            }

            var results = TstarData.AsEnumerable().Join(M5Data.AsEnumerable(),
                a => a.Field<String>("VehicleName"),
                b => b.Field<String>("Unit_NO"),
                    (a, b) =>
                    {

                        DataRow row = ComTable.NewRow();
                        row.ItemArray = a.ItemArray.Concat(b.ItemArray).ToArray();
                        ComTable.Rows.Add(row);
                        return row;

                    });

            SQLDataTable.ItemsSource = ComTable.DefaultView;
            }
```

Comment: I am building a cost center tool in C# with WPF

Comment: Are the servers remotely linked to each other, so you can query both at the same time?

Comment: yes I am  pulling them in at the same time.

Comment: i did two public datatables one getsqldata other one getoracledata

then ran a new one that got the information together

var SQLData = getsqlData();
var OraData = getOracleData();

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using two nested for loops.

The outer for loop would iterate through each row in the SQL DataTable.

The inner loop would iterate through each row in the Oracle DataTable, and if there is a match, it would store the match somewhere (perhaps in a list).

**Optional Hints**

- Assuming that each number plate only occurs once, we could optimise this code by breaking out of the inner loop as soon as we get a match.
- We cannot rely on the rows coming back in the same order. Thus, we cannot naively compare row 1 from SQL against row 1 from Oracle.

Comment: the only problem with that is i still have to show the ones that didn't have a match

Comment: No problems. If you get to the end of the inner loop and you haven't found a match, and then you add the item to an unmatched list. At the end, spin through the unmatched list and print them all out.

Comment: oh okay that makes sense can you please view my code above this is what I got so far it brings in the columns but not the data

Comment: It looks like you are iterating through the columns. You have to iterate through the rows instead.

Comment: I figured out my problem i was using + 2 instead of +"2" and it could not find a match.

Answer (score 0):

my code is based off grabbing columns that are not populated yet in the datagrid I call two datatable on the code behind to populate the table and also us excel sheets. If anyone needs this information i can help.

I connect to SQL,  Oracle and load excel sheets to make a comparison on data